# Matlab: Colour grade a Constellation Diagram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I am using Matlab. I have a large column vector consisting of complex values. e.g.

> data=[
>       -0.4447 + 0.6263i
>       0.3114 + 0.8654i
>       0.7201 + 0.6808i
>       0.7566 + 0.8177i
>      -0.7532 - 0.8085i
>      -0.7851 + 0.6042i
>      -0.7351 - 0.8725i
>      -0.4580 + 0.8053i
>       0.5775 - 0.6369i
>       0.7073 - 0.5565i
>       0.4939 - 0.7015i
>      -0.4981 + 0.8112i
>       ....
>      ]

This represents a constellation diagram which is shown below.

[image]

I would like to colour grade the constellation points depending on frequency at a particular point. I presume I need to create a histogram, but I am not sure how to do this using complex vectors and then how to plot the colour grade.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand what you exactly mean by "*to colour grade the constellation points depending on frequency at a particular point*". Can you please be more explicit about the math of what you want to do?

Comment: Do you want to plot the constellation diagram of an OFDM signal with different colors for each subcarrier?

Comment: Sorry, but colour grade I mean: "The Color Grade feature provides an inﬁnite persistence plot where the frequency of occurrence of a point on the plot is indicated by its color." An example is given here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujlnb29xvybmbtr/colour%20grade%20QPSK.JPG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do a heat map:

```
histdata = [real(data), imag(data)];
nbins_x = nbins_y = 10; 
[N, C] = hist3(histdata, [nbins_x, nbins_y]); % the second argument is optional.
imagesc(N);
```

Here `hist3` creates the histogram-matrix, `imagesc` draws a scaled heat-map. If you prefer a 3d-visualization, just type `hist3(histdata)`.

If you just right-click on N in the workspace window there are plenty of other visualization options. I suggest also trying `contourf(N)` which is a filled contour plot.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Heat-map was exactly the phrase I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want to do is to find a two-2 histogram. The easiest way would be to separate out the real and imaginary points, and use the [hist2d](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14205-2d-histogram) function, like this:

```
rdata=real(data);
idata=imag(data);

hist2d([rdata;idata]);
```